# Sending mail with subject as variable

Tags: bash, shell, email, command-line, command

Here i want to send mail using unix shell scripting.

I use the following script for simple mailing:

```
echo 'Message body goes here' | mail -s 'subject line goes here' email@provider.com
```

**Note**: Now i want to send mail with the subject which comes from other file using the variable as shown below.

**File 1**:

The file contains the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
subjectvariable="Subject is here" 
export $subjectvariable
```

I want to get this `$subjectvariable` should be used in the mail command as a variable.

**My try**:

**File 2**:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Message body goes here' | mail -s "$subjectvariable" email@provider.com
```

But in the output i am not getting the subject.

Variable works file for just echo command as shown below in the image:

[image]

Comment: I think it should be `export subjectvariable="Subject is here` in the first script. Note: The variable will be only available for sub processes. So file 2 has to be run from file 1.

Comment: You need to source the subject script using `source ./setSubject.sh` to be able to set variable in your current shell

Comment: @anubhava, I have exported that variable. So there is still need to source file into the current shell?

Comment: Export doesn't make it available to parent shell

Comment: @anubhava, Okay. Let me show you something. Just check my updated post and please reply for that.

Comment: You need to be doing `. file1.sh`

Comment: @anubhava,Getting an error: `source` not found. When i insert `source ./file1.sh` in file2.sh

Comment: Use `. ./file1.sh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

file 1 :

```
#!/bin/bash
subjectvariable="Subject is here" 
export subjectvariable=$subjectvariable
```

and source file 1 before exec file2

Comment: Getting an error: `source` not found. When i insert `source ./file1.sh`.

Comment: a bit late, try source file.sh without ./
./ is for exec not source